# Maven dependencies for AWS S3 classes

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

Could anyone help me with maven and AWS?
In the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/setup-project-maven.html), they explain that we need to add the following dependencies:

```
<project>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.X.X</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

I did that. And I wanted to add dependencies to use S3 classes (like [AmazonS3Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html) and such). In [mavenrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3), I found the package S3 but when I add it in my pom.xml file, IntelliJ can not find it.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.923</version>
</dependency>
```

Could anyone help me and tell me what is wrong with what I'm doing? I've been trying so many option but I can't figure it out. All I want is to use S3 objects from a JAVA program (basically an aws lambda function)

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to go with/use AWS SDK for Java 1.x, then you need to refer [this](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/java/example_code/s3/pom.xml) maven as example. Else, if you opt for AWS SDK for Java 2.x, then use the below mentioned maven dependency configuration and refer [this](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/S3ObjectOperations.java) java example.

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.51</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Hi amitf, I've tried that as well. But I can't use class AmazonS3, S3Objects, etc like in the documentation here: 
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/java/example_code/s3/src/main/java/aws/example/s3/GetObject2.java
Any suggestion?